# Space or padding between the td and its :after

Tags: html, css

I have a table with `tr>th`, `td` with pseudo element `:after`. I have CSS

```
table thead tr th:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 19%;
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray
}

.panel_content table thead tr th.site {
  border-top: 2px solid lightblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[image]
How can i remove space between :after and th element.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please check my edits

Answer (score 0):

The space is due to `width: 19%;` in your :after section. That will take up 19% of the table width, based on how wide the table is allowed to be by its container.

Comment: what should i do, it is also coming in px case

Comment: Oh, you have padding applied to all th elements, so the space in your content declaration gets padded. Try resetting the padding in your after psuedoelement.